# Is there a method to do arithmetic with SciPy's random variables?

Tags: python, random, scipy

SciPy's `stats` module have objects of the type "random variable" (they call it `rv_frozen`). It makes it easy to plot, say, **cdf**'s of random variables of a given distribution. Here's a very simple example:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
n = stats.norm()
x = linspace(-3, 3)
y = n.cdf(x)
plot(x, y)
```

I wondered whether there's a way of doing basic arithmetic manipulations on such random variables. The following example is a wishful thinking (it doesn't work).

```
du_list = [stats.randint(2, 5) for _ in xrange(100)]
du_avg = sum(du_list) / len(du_list)
x = linspace(0, 10)
y = du_avg.cdf(x)
plot(x, y)
```

This wishful-thinking example should produce the graph of the cumulative distribution function of the random variable which is the average of 100 i.i.d. random variables, each is distributed uniformly on the set `{2,3,4}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I realize this is a bit late, but I figured I'd answer in case anyone else needs this in the future. I needed the same functionality recently and even thought about extending scipy's `rv_discrete` to implement this, but then I found [PaCAL](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v57/i10/paper).

PaCAL is a Python software package for doing arithmetic on random variables and it supports quite a few distributions, including continuous distributions. There is even some support for bivariate joint distributions. Available as a package on PyPI. Only for Python 2.x though.

EDIT: The [PaCAL repo on Github](https://github.com/jszymon/pacal) now supports Python 3.x as well.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that! I'll have a look at this package. Looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

The method that matches your description exactly doesn't exist. The cdf of different distributions are all defined int the **/scipy/stats/distributions.py` source file. For example:

Boltzman distribution CDF (Line 7675):

```
def _cdf(self, x, lambda_, N):
    k = floor(x)
    return (1-exp(-lambda_*(k+1)))/(1-exp(-lambda_*N))
```

You can, estimate the MLE and then call the cdf method, see this sample:

```
import scipy.stats as ss
unknown=np.random.normal(loc=1.1, scale=2.0, size=100)
Loc, Scale=ss.norm.fit_loc_scale(unknown) #making a MLE fit
unknown_cdf=lambda x: ss.norm.cdf(x, loc=Loc, scale=Scale) #the cdf of the MLE to the data
plt.plot(np.linspace(-10, 10), unknown_cdf(np.linspace(-10, 10)), '-')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could compute it by hand.

With X the random variable created as the sum of the Xi, i random variables uniformly distributed U(2,5). Sample your distribution created by X to obtain the pdf, and integrate to obtain the cdf.

Or you could try to find an analytical solution for this problem.

See the [Irwin-Hall distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution)
and the [related discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370228/probability-distribution-of-a-sum-of-uniform-random-variables) on Math-stackexchange.